# Power calculations with a continuous independent variable in a case-control study with pair-matched data

Tags: statistical-power, paired-data, case-control-study

So I have been struggling with this matter quite a while now and still have not found a solution to this problem. In fact similar questions have been asked here before but no answer was provided to my knowledge.

So, the dependent variable in our study is binary and the main independent variable included in the model is a continuous variable which varies approximately between 0 and 10.

With alpha = 0.05 and beta = 0.2 (power = 0.8) we would like to make ad hoc power calculations of the required sample size. The expected OR for a one unit increase of the independent variable (eg. 1 -> 2) is 1.01. The variance of the independent variable is available.

Because our case-control data is pair-matched (1:3), we will be using conditional logistic regression in the analysis.

Do any of you know a way to tackle this problem? Thanks in advance!